# How to configure Serilog to write logs inn SQL Server for .NET 5 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, serilog

I have implemented an exact flow in my code as mentioned in below link but still I cant see any logs written in my Log table. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implementation-serilog-in-asp-net-core-5-0-application-with-database/

Can someone please tell me am I missing something here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nitz Code is exact same as mentioned in link in question.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved now. I was missing schema name in my code where we configure the Logger in Main method. When I have added that, its working now.